# How to make a folder on external SDCARD (Which is inserted from out side the device)?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to create a folder on my external storage (inserted SD card). I tried in several ways, but it just create a folder on device storage. I have seen to create on some android app. Please help me by providing a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
 File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/boyan/");

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();

    }
```

Permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: As you have seen getExternalStorageDirectory() does not deliver a path to an SD card. For the rest your code is ok but you should of course check the return value of mkdirs(). You better ask how to determine the path to your SD card.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder_name");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}`

Comment: Then use that name in place of "Folder_name"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
Here it is.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Above code return "/storage/sdcard0", But if you want to make a folder on external SD Card you need "/storage/sdcard1". so try to do something like this

```
 File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().replace("0", "1") + "/boyan/");
```